# fetch environment variables in a cgi with haskell/hugs without a package

Tags: haskell, environment-variables, cgi, hugs

I am writing a cgi-script in Haskell.
I am restricted to use only hugs/runhugs.

```
#!/opt/local/bin/runhugs

module Main where

main = do
        putStrLn ("content-type: text/plain\n")
        putStrLn ("Hello, Server!")
```

So far so good.
But now I want to get the server's environment variables.
For example the "SCRIPT_NAME" environment variable.

With bash I can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "content-type: text/plain;"
echo ""

echo $SCRIPT_NAME
```

With the result: `/path/to/script.cgi` in the browser-window.

For Haskell I found something alike: `script <- getEnv "SCRIPT_NAME"`,
but

```
#!/opt/local/bin/runhugs

module Main where

main = do
        putStrLn ("content-type: text/plain\n")
        scriptname <- getEnv "SCRIPT_NAME"
        putStrLn scriptname
```

doesn't work.

Is it possible to do it in a way sort of like that ?

1. plain without an import, or
2. with an import possible in hugs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `import System.Environment (getEnv)`.